# how to efficiently create a view model from multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, strongly-typed-dataset

I have the following ViewModel:

```
 public class EmployeeCatalogModel
    {
        public List<StringCatalogModel> EmployeeType { get; set; }
        public List<IntCatalogModel> JobTitle { get; set; }
        public List<IntCatalogModel> ProfitCenter { get; set; }
        public List<IntCatalogModel> Location { get; set; }
        public List<IntCatalogModel> HolidayTemplate { get; set; }

    }
```

Each property can be `StringCatalogModel` or `IntCatalogModel` depending on the identity of each table:

Model where the `Id` is `integer`

```
public class IntCatalogModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Model where the `Id` is `string`

```
    public class StringCatalogModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Ok, so the magic happens here... I will bring from my Stored Procedure 5 selects (for each catalog) and then I have to create `EmployeeCatalogModel` from there.

What I have now is:

```
using(DbCommand cmd1 = _db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_employee_catalogs_get")) {

    // instantiate my view model class
    EmployeeCatalogModel model = new EmployeeCatalogModel();

    using(DataSet ds = _db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd1)) {

      // loop through each table so I can instantiate the corresponding collection
      foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables){

        switch(dt.TableName){

          case "EmployeeType":

             model.EmployeeType = new List<StringCatalogModel>();

            break;

          case "JobTitle":

            model.JobTitle = new List<IntCatalogModel>();

            break;
        }


        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows){

          // here I have to know what if I need to create an item of IntCatalogModel or StringCatalogModel and added to its corresponding Collection
          // ?? any better way to do this????


        }

      }

    }
}
```

Any way to perform this in a better way?

Comment: Why not use an ORM?  (Like Entity-Framework for example).

Comment: Im using ORM in this application but for this method I prefer to go Stored Procedure

Comment: Also I don't think Entity Framework could do this with better performance that a simple SP.

Comment: So EF supports Stored Procedures, [including Stored Procedures that return multiple results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx), which leads me back to why not use EF?

Comment: Good link, interesting, but... do you agree that it's not a good practice to return a EF entity to my view, the best practice says that you have to return business model. so if using that approach, i will have to Map that EF entity to my business Entity

Comment: @VAAA Regardless of which route you go (either an ORM like EF or writing your own SQL/Stored Procedure) you would ideally still have some sort of abstraction between your view-models and your database access.